# PCB house raising through hole pad error

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, integrated-circuit, eaglecad, breakout

A fab house is raising a strange error on through hole pad connections. In the top layer all connections are made but they are saying the bottom layer is left unconnected.

Its a breakout board for a 32 pin QFN IC. I used a 8-pin through hole connector and connected it to each side of the Chip and connected all the IC pins with each 8-pin connectors on the top layer.

But now the fab house is saying, the bottom layer has pads and there is no connections. Why is it required?

Raised exception - https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3tW8HqE_ubMMTI4WFBDSDlyd19Ib3NCNU5sS1hkVHl1UUw4/view?usp=sharing

Gerber Files and its images - https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3tW8HqE_ubMNTZiTlNBamhBRTJTeTlQcE41MVFyNWllT2Uw/view?usp=sharing

BRD file - https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3tW8HqE_ubMeWVCRm5NRzlhOFdFQzJFeUpYV2VFamVpR25V/view?usp=sharing

SCHEM file - https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3tW8HqE_ubMWnEtcERCbkZ4UlJSc3Y2QW1pREs1dmVBQkhF/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You need to find a better way to include the relevant information directly in your question. No one is going to download and unpack a bunch of zip files in order to answer what is probably a relatively simple question.

Comment: Without doing a lot of digging through this, just make sure that your pads are plated through holes, otherwise I don't see anything wrong with this- they are perhaps just being picky (unlike most Chinese makers who will make whatever is on the Gerbers no matter how obvious the error- sorry your fault).

Comment: Did you somehow say that the through-hole pads should *not* be plated through? That *would* be peculiar, and might involve a slightly unusual manufacturing process to drill the holes *after* plating. This is only a WAG.

Comment: @gbulmer  They should be plated-through. This board probably has both- the 'mouse bites' should be unplated. It's indeed a separate process, but a very commonly required one.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany - I agree it is not weird to have some unplated holes or routing. However, it would be unusual to have a through hole part soldered into unplated through-hole pads. That's why I made the comment.

Answer (score 2):

If it looks like you expect - and it does - there's nothing wrong with that. They just think it's somewhat odd, and possibly an easy mistake, so instead of having a sad customer they want to make sure it's OK before continuing.

Note that they never claim it is *required*, as you write in the question.

Comment: Agree. The fab house is keeping an eye out for its customers - good for them. And note that their proposed solution is to not make any changes, just make it as drawn, but they want confirmation from the originator.